# contenido repetido con .clone() jquery mostrar aleatoriamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una gran duda, quiero hacer una lista de imágenes que se repitan así como esta en el código utilizando `jquery` puedo clonar los elementos `li`, pero quiero que a la hora de mostrar los elementos repetidos, salgan en desorden, ahora mismo están saliendo en orden **(1,2,3,1,2,3)** así sucesivamente, quiero que salga de forma aleatoria **(2,1,3,1,3,2,3,1)** etc... !

> ¿Me puede ayudar?

```js
/**
 * Endless Scroll plugin for jQuery
 *
 * v1.4.8
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Fred Wu
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * // using default options
 * $(document).endlessScroll();
 *
 * // using some custom options
 * $(document).endlessScroll({
 *   fireOnce: false,
 *   fireDelay: false,
 *   loader: "<div class=\"loading\"><div>",
 *   callback: function(){
 *     alert("test");
 *   }
 * });
 *
 * Configuration options:
 *
 * bottomPixels  integer          the number of pixels from the bottom of the page that triggers the event
 * fireOnce      boolean          only fire once until the execution of the current event is completed
 * fireDelay     integer          delay the subsequent firing, in milliseconds, 0 or false to disable delay
 * loader        string           the HTML to be displayed during loading
 * data          string|function  plain HTML data, can be either a string or a function that returns a string,
 *                                when passed as a function it accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number
 *                                of times the event triggered during the current page session)
 * insertAfter   string           jQuery selector syntax: where to put the loader as well as the plain HTML data
 * callback      function         callback function, accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number of times
 *                                the event triggered during the current page session)
 * resetCounter  function         resets the fire sequence counter if the function returns true, this function
 *                                could also perform hook actions since it is applied at the start of the event
 * ceaseFire     function         stops the event (no more endless scrolling) if the function returns true
 *
 * Usage tips:
 *
 * The plugin is more useful when used with the callback function, which can then make AJAX calls to retrieve content.
 * The fire sequence argument (for the callback function) is useful for 'pagination'-like features.
 */

(function($){

  $.fn.endlessScroll = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      bottomPixels: 50,
      fireOnce: true,
      fireDelay: 150,
      loader: "<br />Loading...<br />",
      data: "",
      insertAfter: "div:last",
      resetCounter: function() { return false; },
      callback: function() { return true; },
      ceaseFire: function() { return false; }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var firing       = true;
    var fired        = false;
    var fireSequence = 0;

    if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
      firing = false;
    }

    if (firing === true) {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
          firing = false;
          return; // Scroll will still get called, but nothing will happen
        }

        if (this == document || this == window) {
          var is_scrollable = $(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels;
        } else {
          // calculates the actual height of the scrolling container
          var inner_wrap = $(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap", this);
          if (inner_wrap.length == 0) {
            inner_wrap = $(this).wrapInner("<div class=\"endless_scroll_inner_wrap\" />").find(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap");
          }
          var is_scrollable = inner_wrap.length > 0 &&
            (inner_wrap.height() - $(this).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels);
        }

        if (is_scrollable && (options.fireOnce == false || (options.fireOnce == true && fired != true))) {
          if (options.resetCounter.apply(this) === true) fireSequence = 0;

          fired = true;
          fireSequence++;

          $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_loader\">" + options.loader + "</div>");

          data = typeof options.data == 'function' ? options.data.apply(this, [fireSequence]) : options.data;

          if (data !== false) {
            $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_data\">" + data + "</div>");
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").hide().fadeIn();
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").removeAttr("id");

            options.callback.apply(this, [fireSequence]);

            if (options.fireDelay !== false || options.fireDelay !== 0) {
              $("body").after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_marker\"></div>");
              // slight delay for preventing event firing twice
              $("div#endless_scroll_marker").fadeTo(options.fireDelay, 1, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                fired = false;
              });
            }
            else {
              fired = false;
            }
          }

          $("div#endless_scroll_loader").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);


// Script
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).endlessScroll({
        inflowPixels: 300,
        callback: function() {
      var $img = $('#images li:nth-last-child(5)').clone();
      $('#images').append($img);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 640px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Infinite Scrolling through Images</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <h1>Infinite Scrolling, Demo 3</h1>

  <ul id="images">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

De la siguiente manera:

Vas a notar que primero calculo la cantidad de imagenes que tenes "cargadas"

```
var cantidad_imagenes = $('#images li').size();
```

Luego en base a esa cantidad elijo una posición de alguna de ellas al azar y la guardo en la variable random.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));
```

Por ultimo clono la imagen en la pocicion que acabo de calcular y la agregamos al final.

```
var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();
$('#images').append(img);
```

A Continuacion la porcion de codigo completa:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cantidad_imagenes = $('#images li').size();

    $(document).endlessScroll({
      inflowPixels: 300,
      callback: function() {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));
        var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();
        $('#images').append(img);
      }
    });
});
```

Te lo dejo funcionando en un fiddle.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Saludos.

```js
/**
 * Endless Scroll plugin for jQuery
 *
 * v1.4.8
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Fred Wu
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * // using default options
 * $(document).endlessScroll();
 *
 * // using some custom options
 * $(document).endlessScroll({
 *   fireOnce: false,
 *   fireDelay: false,
 *   loader: "<div class=\"loading\"><div>",
 *   callback: function(){
 *     alert("test");
 *   }
 * });
 *
 * Configuration options:
 *
 * bottomPixels  integer          the number of pixels from the bottom of the page that triggers the event
 * fireOnce      boolean          only fire once until the execution of the current event is completed
 * fireDelay     integer          delay the subsequent firing, in milliseconds, 0 or false to disable delay
 * loader        string           the HTML to be displayed during loading
 * data          string|function  plain HTML data, can be either a string or a function that returns a string,
 *                                when passed as a function it accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number
 *                                of times the event triggered during the current page session)
 * insertAfter   string           jQuery selector syntax: where to put the loader as well as the plain HTML data
 * callback      function         callback function, accepts one argument: fire sequence (the number of times
 *                                the event triggered during the current page session)
 * resetCounter  function         resets the fire sequence counter if the function returns true, this function
 *                                could also perform hook actions since it is applied at the start of the event
 * ceaseFire     function         stops the event (no more endless scrolling) if the function returns true
 *
 * Usage tips:
 *
 * The plugin is more useful when used with the callback function, which can then make AJAX calls to retrieve content.
 * The fire sequence argument (for the callback function) is useful for 'pagination'-like features.
 */

(function($){

  $.fn.endlessScroll = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      bottomPixels: 50,
      fireOnce: true,
      fireDelay: 150,
      loader: "<br />Loading...<br />",
      data: "",
      insertAfter: "div:last",
      resetCounter: function() { return false; },
      callback: function() { return true; },
      ceaseFire: function() { return false; }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var firing       = true;
    var fired        = false;
    var fireSequence = 0;

    if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
      firing = false;
    }

    if (firing === true) {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
          firing = false;
          return; // Scroll will still get called, but nothing will happen
        }

        if (this == document || this == window) {
          var is_scrollable = $(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels;
        } else {
          // calculates the actual height of the scrolling container
          var inner_wrap = $(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap", this);
          if (inner_wrap.length == 0) {
            inner_wrap = $(this).wrapInner("<div class=\"endless_scroll_inner_wrap\" />").find(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap");
          }
          var is_scrollable = inner_wrap.length > 0 &&
            (inner_wrap.height() - $(this).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels);
        }

        if (is_scrollable && (options.fireOnce == false || (options.fireOnce == true && fired != true))) {
          if (options.resetCounter.apply(this) === true) fireSequence = 0;

          fired = true;
          fireSequence++;

          $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_loader\">" + options.loader + "</div>");

          data = typeof options.data == 'function' ? options.data.apply(this, [fireSequence]) : options.data;

          if (data !== false) {
            $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_data\">" + data + "</div>");
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").hide().fadeIn();
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").removeAttr("id");

            options.callback.apply(this, [fireSequence]);

            if (options.fireDelay !== false || options.fireDelay !== 0) {
              $("body").after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_marker\"></div>");
              // slight delay for preventing event firing twice
              $("div#endless_scroll_marker").fadeTo(options.fireDelay, 1, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                fired = false;
              });
            }
            else {
              fired = false;
            }
          }

          $("div#endless_scroll_loader").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);


// Script
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cantidad_imagenes = $('#images li').size();

    $(document).endlessScroll({
      inflowPixels: 300,
      callback: function() {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidad_imagenes));
        var img =  $('#images').find("li:eq("+random+")").clone();
        $('#images').append(img);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 640px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Infinite Scrolling through Images</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <h1>Infinite Scrolling, Demo 3</h1>

  <ul id="images">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias aunque ya lo habia resuelto, de otra manera aunque es bueno aprender cosas nuevas y tu me has enseñado algo nuevo, gracias por tu ayuda amigo leonardo espero mejorar para poder ayudar a la gente ! @leonardo cabré !